# Reply All in Outlook from Excel Macro

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

When you click reply all in outlook, it will open a new email box, but show the previous email thread underneath the body of your email. I am trying to Reply All to the selected email in outlook and input information. I want to do this all from a Macro in Excel. My problem is that if I try to write in the body of the Reply All, it erases the entire previous email thread.

```
Sub test()

Dim mail 'object/mail item iterator
Dim replyall 'object which will represent the reply email

For Each mail In Outlook.Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection
    If mail.Class = olMail Then
        Set replyall = mail.replyall
        With replyall
            '.Body = "blah blah hello world"  '<-- uncomment and it will delete the thread
            .Display
        End With
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Note: the closest I've come is this, but it deletes my signature, the email separator, and the header info from the latest email:

```
.Body = "blah blah hello world" & mail.body
```

Any solutions are appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: looks like Dmitry has answered your question. Ron De Bruin writes some excellent OL orientated code: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff519602(v=office.11).aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the plain text, you can do

```
.Body = "blah blah hello world" & vbCrLf & .Body
```

If you want to preserve formatting, you will need to insert your string into the `replyall.HTMLBody` property (you cannot just concatenate two HTML strings).